# How to close windows by middle clicking on application title bar?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I wish to use mouse' middle button to close various applications so that when I middle click a windows title bar, it actually closes it.

[image]

Is it possible to do it by configuring windows or using external tools? If it matters, I am using Windows 7.

Comment: wait for autohotkey guys ...

Comment: @Revolter: LOL, sure enough 3 hours later, see @CGA's answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [Autohotkey script](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/7718-mbutton-close-windowstaskbartitlebar-open-ie-links/) that does this.

Comment: I don't know how to use the `code` when open the link. Please educate me more. 7plus app as mentioned by @Hemant is pretty easy to use

Comment: If you're using Win NT6.* (Vista / 7 / 8), make sure you replace the following code to avoid the "Shut Down Windows" prompts when middle-clicking on the taskbar: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/7718-mbutton-close-windowstaskbartitlebar-open-ie-links/page-2#entry252641

Comment: Doesn't work on all windows or secondary monitors. At least on Windows 7, anyway. The app @Hemant mentioned (7plus) works far better and it is just an AutoHotkey wrapper anyway.

Comment: Obsolete hyperlink. New: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/7718-mbutton-close-windowstaskbartitlebar-open-ie-links/

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon [this application](http://code.google.com/p/7plus/) which lets you close application by middle click and lots more. Seems pretty good.